# Webfont characters display properly on webpages but become square symbols when inspect elements in Chrome

Tags: fonts, webfonts

The font is TrueType Outlines. When I click to view the font, there is no English characters and numbers in it, but only that language font characters. I can only use the English keyboard with this font to make it work, cannot use that language keyboard.

When I generate webfonts to use on webpages by using this site https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator, it works and I can see the font charaters display properly on the wepages. However, since this fonts works with the English keyboard, I have to type the texts in Mirosoft Word first in order to get the characters,then copy and paste into the webpages. As mentioned, the fonts display properly on the webpages. However, the text are square symbols when I inspect the elements in Chrome. So, the square symbols, rather than that font characters, will show up in the Google index and could hurt SEO, right? Anyway to solve this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you're worried about search, not about viewing text in the developer tools.

Search indexes record the Unicode strings, not their appearance. But your private use characters are just that: private use, meaning that their semantics is defined only by private agreement. Sorry, but unless you have a private agreement with Google and every person in the world that uses Google search, there are no guarantees of search working the way you want, and really no point worrying about SEO.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. the point is the font itself. Anyway to fix the font to have unicode sctrong?